# second argument type error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I wanna set a background color to my layout.
The problem is it gives me:

Wrong 2nd argument type. required int.
I just change `R.color.red` to `color variable`

```
  //add background color header
        String color = pref.getString("color", null);
        if(color != null) {
            color = "R.color." + color;
            LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menuHeader);
            rl.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, color));
        }
```

what is wrong? how to solve?

Comment: color ir a variable that I get in sharedpreferences. it is red, blue... but to set color I need its reference in style.xml `R.color.red` the problem is if I put R.color.red it works, but I need to pass a dinamic color there.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I added an answer, let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContextCompat.getColor` is waiting for something like `R.color.red`, which is actually of type `int`. You're passing a `String` and that's wrong of course.

You should do something like this:

```
String color = pref.getString("color", null);
if(color != null) {
      int colorId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(color, "color", this.getPackageName());
      LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menuHeader);
      rl.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorId));
}
```

Also, make sure that if you get `X` for `color`, you also have a color named like:
 `<color name="X">#000000</color>`

Comment: thank you again! just one more question, can I use this to `setTheme(colorId);` too? I need to use the same thing, but now to change theme using `R.style.Yellow` not r.color.

Comment: @RickJoe, yes, you will have to do something like `this.getResources().getIdentifier(styleNameString, "style", this.getPackageName())`

Answer (score 1):

`color` should be int.

So change your code to :

```
    String colorString = pref.getString("color", null);
    if(colorString != null) {
        colorString = "R.color." + colorString;

        int myColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorString);

        LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menuHeader);
        rl.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, myColor));
    }
```

Comment: oh, but getColor is deprecated?

Comment: True! Use `ContextCompat.getColor()` then - let me change my answer

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you save the String value for the color instead?

```
String color = getResources().getString(R.color.red);
```

Save this to shared preference,so the value will be some #123456
Then fetch it from shared preference `String color = pref.getString("color", null);`
then rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));